# SEO for dynamic web pages

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, seo

I've created a website where some pages are dynamically created using JavaScript and PHP.

for exmaple: http://parkplanner.areitravel.co.il/park.php?id=6.
the content of pages is changed based on the parameter "id".

I know that a few years ago, there was no way for crawlers to scan this type of pages.
But now maybe there is a way or best practice to create dynamic pages so search engines will scan them and better SEO compatibility?

Thanks!

Comment: you can also add sitemap to your routes so crawlers can find your pages easier

Answer (score 0):

use php to add content relevant to the page into you title bar, also the image name and alt tags, you can also dynamically add in your keywords and description.

I develop in ColdFusion but all our SEO is controlled Dynamically according to the page, simply create the components dynamically. The search engines go to every possible link so they will also go through your dynamic pages

Comment: Just to make sure i got it correctly, you mean I should use only PHP to enter the content from the database without the JS in the middle?

Comment: Yeah you can do that, there is no need for JS